# Why do I need to add space before = in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In the following code , I have to add space before = , why ?

I think `private val listofMDetail: MutableList<MDetail>=` *(No space before =)* would be OK, but in fact, the Android Studio 3.1.3 give me an error.

```
  private val listofMDetail: MutableList<MDetail> =           //I have to add space before =
            try{
                myGson.fromJson<MutableList<MDetail>>(mJson)?: mutableListOf<MDetail>()  //Load
            }catch(e:Exception) {
                e.message?.let{ logError("Paser: "+it)}
                throw Exception(e)
            }
```

Comment: >= means something else in Kotlin doesn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol `>=` is read as **greater than or equal to**, that is why the compiler show the error `Expecting a '>'`.

Just add the space, as recommended in the `Kotlin` style guide maintained by Google: https://android.github.io/kotlin-guides/style.html